# How to make concatenated ASCII art go across rather than down

Tags: python, string, ascii, ascii-art

I want to join strings of ASCII art together, but when I concatenate them it goes down rather than across. How can I join ASCII art horizontally in Python?

```
""" 

               :;;:;``                 
              :;';;';                  
              ,'''';:                  
              ::''';,                  
               ''+';                   
                ,',`                   
                 ;`                    
                `;;                    
               :;;;;                   
               '';;';                  
              ,,+'+;;                  
              .'++';:                  
              .':#+;,`                 
               `;';.                   
                   `  

               :;;:;``                 
              :;';;';                  
              ,'''';:                  
              ::''';,                  
               ''+';                   
                ,',`                   
                 ;`                    
                `;;                    
               :;;;;                   
               '';;';                  
              ,,+'+;;                  
              .'++';:                  
              .':#+;,`                 
               `;';.                   
                   ` """
```

Comment: What code generates this?

Comment: @ForceBru looks like a string literal :)

Comment: it uses print(""" ***image here*** "","""***image here***"")

Comment: I think what you want to do is pick one line at a time from both strings and concatenate them, thereby producing lines in a new string.

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is concatenate each line rather than the whole thing.

Provided each line in your ASCII art is the same length, you can do something like this:

```
a = """|   |
|---|
|   |"""

b = """--|--
  |  
--|--"""

art = (a, b)    

print('\n'.join(' '.join(pair) for pair in zip(*(s.split('\n') for s in art))))
```

Which outputs this

```
|   | --|--
|---|   |
|   | --|--
```

### Explanation

First of all, I initialise `a` and `b` to contain two bits of ASCII art and store them in a tuple `art`. This could also be a list or some other container. It just needs to be something that's iterable.

Most of what's going on happens in the last line, so let's break it down. Working from the inner expression outwards:

```
(s.split('\n') for s in art)
```

This is a generator expression. It loops through `art` and splits each item it finds on `'\n'` which is the newline character. Thus, it splits each item in `art` into lines.

```
zip(*(s.split('\n') for s in art))
```

`zip` is a weird function to explain, so I'll use an example: `zip((1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6))` returns an iterable containing `(1, 4)`, `(2, 5)` and (3, 6)`. 
What this means in this context is that it takes a line from each piece of ASCII art in sequence and puts them in tuples.

```
' '.join(pair) for pair in zip(*(s.split('\n') for s in art))
```

This takes the result of the `zip` call and joins each pair with a space. That is, it concatenates each of the lines in each of the sections of ASCII art with a space in between.

```
'\n'.join(' '.join(pair) for pair in zip(*(s.split('\n') for s in art)))
```

This joins each of the resulting lines with a newline, resulting in a single string.

Answer (score 1):

Use .split() to split on new lines, then .join() to merge them. Use .format() to make sure the strings do not merge e.g.:

Here is a function that puts it all together:

```
def join_art(s1,s2,str_between=''):
     lines1 = s1.split('\n')
     lines2 = s2.split('\n')
     max_dist = max([len(s) for s in lines1])
     f_str = '{:<'+str(max_dist)+'}{}{}'
     s3 = "\n".join([f_str.format(str1,str_between,str2) for str1,str2 in zip(lines1,lines2)])
     return s3
```

example usage:

```
In [31]: s1 = """
 (~\       _ 
  \ \     / \ 
   \ \___/ /\\ 
    | , , |  ~ 
    ( =v= ) 
     ` ^ ' mh 
 """

In [32]: s2 = """ 
            /\ /| 
           |||| | 
            \ | \ 
        _ _ /  @ @ 
      /    \   =>X<= 
    /|      |   / 
    \|     /__| | 
      \_____\ \__\ """

In [58]: print (join_art(s1,s2))

(~\       _              /\ /| 
 \ \     / \            |||| | 
  \ \___/ /\             \ | \ 
   | , , |  ~        _ _ /  @ @ 
   ( =v= )         /    \   =>X<= 
    ` ^ ' mh     /|      |   / 
                 \|     /__| | 

In [59]: print (join_art(s1,s2,str_between=' |==| '))
               |==|  
(~\       _    |==|            /\ /| 
 \ \     / \   |==|           |||| | 
  \ \___/ /\   |==|            \ | \ 
   | , , |  ~  |==|        _ _ /  @ @ 
   ( =v= )     |==|      /    \   =>X<= 
    ` ^ ' mh   |==|    /|      |   / 
               |==|    \|     /__| |
```

*Art for examples taken from [here](http://www.chris.com/ascii/index.php?art=animals%2Frabbits)